# Flipping the styled container

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-grid, css-transforms

This is the pen I am working on and I want to create something more interesting for my portfolio, but I've stuck on the part when I want to have the same elements on the right side of the screen doing the same expanding but to the other direction (mirrored/flipped/reverted/opposite).

The full code can be viewed in the pen. https://codepen.io/benjaminj/pen/oNqWPRb

As You can see I have used scale but this also flipped and the text inside which is not the end goal of this project. Also when hovering the elements on the right weird tremble occurs which also I don't get from where is coming.

1. I have designed a container with expanding side where the text of the container is revealed. Also a grid seemed to me the best for positioning the elements. Below is the HTML code:
2. Because of the pretty weird and complex (for me) design I have used: before and: after for the text.
3. The elements on the left side are working as a charm, but when I tried to "mirror" those elements on the right side and expand to the center of the screen the troubles started.

But for the element on the right side I used only the scaleX (-1)

```css
.main3 {
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

---

Here is the code

```css
.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  row-gap: 100px;
}

.main {
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.main2 {
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.main3 {
  display: block;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.main3 span {
}

.main3 .background::before {
  width: 35%;
}

.test {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #67ade0;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #93cff1;
  border-width: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 5% 50%, 10% 100%, 5% 100%, 0% 50%, 5% 0%);
}

.background {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #e1effa;
  clip-path: polygon(95% 0, 100% 50%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 0 50%, 5% 0);
  transition: width 6.5s, transform 5s;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.diamondStatic {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #c4e0f5;
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 10% 50%, 5% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.diamondAnimate {
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #c4e0f5;
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 10% 50%, 5% 100%, 0% 50%);
  transition: margin-left 6.5s, transform 5s;
}

.test:hover ~ .background {
  width: 400px;
}

.test:hover ~ .diamondAnimate {
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.background::after {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Managed Services';
}

.background::before {
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget erat maximus, mattis ex sed, aliquet arcu. Maecenas eleifend ornare nulla, id placerat turpis pretium quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.';
}

.innerBtn {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="main2">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="main3">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As You can see from the visual box of the codepen, the element on the right side is trembling and the text is inverted. This issue seems to be outside of my little knowledge and that's the reason for taking the guts and posting here.

PS: I have also tried to rebuild the whole container on another way ( https://codepen.io/benjaminj/pen/zYWwyeQ) but here I stumbled with the background that I want to be visible only in the expanding area.

Comment: _"The full code can be viewed in the pen."_ - that is not enough; a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the test being flipped: You just need to `transform:scaleX(-1)` also the inner div `.background`

For the hover being shaking, is because the horizontal scroll showing then hiding, so use `overflow: hidden` in `.main`

I also improved your code a bit, deleting duplicated properties and other minor stuff

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto auto 100px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  row-gap: 100px;
}

.main {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  overflow: hidden
}

.main2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.main3 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.main3 .background {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.test {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #67ade0;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #93cff1;
  border-width: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 5% 50%, 10% 100%, 5% 100%, 0% 50%, 5% 0%);
}

.background {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #e1effa;
  clip-path: polygon(95% 0, 100% 50%, 95% 100%, 5% 100%, 0 50%, 5% 0);
  transition: width 6.5s, transform 5s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.diamondStatic,
.diamondAnimate {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #c4e0f5;
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 10% 50%, 5% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.diamondStatic {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.diamondAnimate {
  margin-left: -20px;
  transition: margin-left 6.5s, transform 5s;
}

.test:hover~.background {
  width: 400px;
}

.test:hover~.diamondAnimate {
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.background::before {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  content: attr(data-text)
}

.background::after {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-title);
}

.innerBtn {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background" data-title="Managed Services" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget erat maximus, mattis ex sed, aliquet arcu. Maecenas eleifend ornare nulla, id placerat turpis pretium quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="main main2">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background" data-title="Managed Services" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget erat maximus, mattis ex sed, aliquet arcu. Maecenas eleifend ornare nulla, id placerat turpis pretium quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="main main3">
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="diamondStatic"></div>
    <span class="background" data-title="Managed Services" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eget erat maximus, mattis ex sed, aliquet arcu. Maecenas eleifend ornare nulla, id placerat turpis pretium quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu.">
          <button class="innerBtn">CLICK ME</button>
        </span>
    <div class="diamondAnimate"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are You aware how can I apply the text on the right to be constant as it is on the left side(I've already changed the width of .main3 background to 85% so it can correspond to the left side, but still when it expands and shrinks the text tries to fit in the background container which is causing "dynamic" text rendering while expanding and shrinking. Also with the hidden overlap of the main3 container, still the right container is trembling. Thank You in advance for the shared time and effort

Comment: PS: I've managed to clear the issue with the tremble with fixed grid-column-template by percentages, only the issue with the text persists to occur.

Comment: @92Infinitus92 see updated answer for the fix of the text, its in `::before`

Comment: actually exactly the opposite I've meant(sorry if I have expressed myself the wrong way...), like the text to be there and when it expands it just uncovers more from it and when it shrinks just to cover it up, without causing the text to constantly move, like the left elements from the original pen that I've provided